# Adding keywords to entries in bib file with a view to using JabRef as a file explorer / manager

Tags: bibliographies

I have created a bib database of maths textbooks, articles, notes etc. and I want to use JabRef to assign keywords to each entry to take advantage of the file management functionality which would result.

I would be interested to hear from anyone who has done this already, either with JabRef or a similar package. How did you strike a balance between too few and too many keywords?

Two extreme approaches I have in mind are:

1. More or less sticking to top level AMS MSC or a similar classification scheme.
2. Harvesting contents pages and indexes for keywords.

Comment: maybe it's just me, but this seems too open ended, subjective, and probably depends on your particular research area. what kind of advice are you expecting?

Comment: @Juan: I appreciate what you are saying. I was hoping to hear that someone has done this and has useable setup that did not involve too much pain, by which I mean a minimal number of keywords per entry (say at most 6) without sacrificing granularity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using (a slightly modified version of) [RefBase](http://www.refbase.net) to organise my references these days and that allows me to add keywords and to group references.  I've just started using [instiki](http://www.instiki.org) as a place to take notes on these references and that allows me to add "categories" to the pages, which is somewhat akin to keywords, I guess.

Since most of the stuff I index already has MSC and/or arXiv classification (I'm a mathematician), adding my own keywords based on those seems a little pointless.  The scheme I'm currently using is to add keywords based on the paper or idea I was working on when I looked for that reference.  Sometimes if a couple of papers are very closely related then I might use the same keyword for both (usually the name of the first paper).
So corresponding to a couple of my papers, I have articles tagged "hopf" and "comparative smootheology".  If I don't have an actual paper, I'll still try to tag them by the answer to the question "What was I thinking about when I went looking for this?".  So I have papers tagged "loop spaces", even though that covers a wide spectrum of my work.  Lastly, I read the "new on the arXiv" and have a way of automatically importing references from that into my database; these, therefore, aren't articles that I've gone looking for so I tag them by the first connection that came into my head when I read the abstract.  So, in summary, when trying to tag an article I'll ask (in order):

1. What article was I working on?
2. What topic was I thinking about?
3. What (of the above two) does it most remind me of?

Comment: Thanks Andrew, that sounds like a nice setup. From what you've said I think a few keywords akin to top level MSC may be way to proceed. Thereafter, whenever I make use of a resource I'll add keywords that reflect the reasons I checked out that resourse. Also, I'll be sure to add keywords to new items when they're added to my database. Now to retrospectively tag existing items...

Comment: @Colin Pratt: Re your last sentence: I feel your pain!  My database was about 1,500 before I shifted to RefBase and could start adding keywords - plus I have a fair few duplicates to weed out.  Need a _very_ rainy day.